# Python: Convert entire string to lowercase except for substrings in quotes

Tags: python, string, lowercase

I have a python string received from user input.

Let's say the user input is something like this:

```
 I am Enrolled in a course, 'MPhil' since 2014. I LOVE this 'SO MuCH'
```

If this string is stored in a variable called input_string, and I apply .lower() on it, it would convert the whole thing into lowercase.

```
input_string = input_string.lower()
```

Result:

```
i am enrolled in a course, 'mphil' since 2014. i love this 'so much'
```

Here's what I desire the lowercase to do:
Convert everything, except what's in quotes, into lowercase.

```
i am enrolled in a course, 'MPhil' since 2014. i love this 'SO MuCH'
```

Comment: Are you going to account for escaped quotes and/or  unclosed quotes? This affects the complexity.

Comment: No. Only for closed quotes. If there are unclosed quotes, that won't be considered as a quoted substring

Comment: How would you handle something like "Mike's garage is next to Bob's house"? It has no embedded quotes at all, though there are characters between single quote marks.

Comment: I have tried to split the string by single quotes and then join  again but looks like a cumbersome way because of intermediate steps

Comment: "Mike's garage is next to Bob's house" would result into "mike's garage is next to Bob's house"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the combination of negative lookahead, lookbehind, applying word boundaries and using a *replacement function*:

```
>>> s = "I am Enrolled in a course, 'MPhil' since 2014. I LOVE this 'SO MuCH'"
>>> re.sub(r"\b(?<!')(\w+)(?!')\b", lambda match: match.group(1).lower(), s)
"i am enrolled in a course, 'MPhil' since 2014. i love this 'SO MuCH'"
```

Comment: it will likely fail for 'SO MuCH MPhil'?

Comment: @YOU yeah, good example, depending on what the OP wants to do in this case.

Comment: Would want to retain 'SO MuCH MPhil' as ''SO MuCH MPhil', no case change as the whole thing is in between quotes

Answer (score 0):

This is my first stack overflow answer. It's defintely not the most elegant code but it works for your question. You can break this answer down as follows:

1. Split string to a list
2. Create two sub-lists
3. Convert desired sub-list to lower
4. Concatenate sub-lists
5. Print with a join method on the list

Here is the code:

```
string = "I am Enrolled in a course, 'MPhil' since 2014. I LOVE this 'SO MuCH'"  
l = string.split()    #split string to list
lower_l = l[0:11]       
unchanged_l = l[11:]  #create sub-lists with split at 11th element
lower_l = [item.lower() for item in lower_l]    #convert to lower
l = lower_l + unchanged_l    #concatenate
print ' '.join(l)     #print joined list delimited by space
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex pattern to solve this problem for the example string and strings containing any number of words between the single quotes.

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r"(^|' )([\w .,]+)($| ')") 

input_string_1 = "I am Enrolled in a course, 'MPhil' since 2014. I LOVE this 'SO MuCH'"
input_string_2 = "I am Enrolled in a course, 'MPhil' since 2014. I LOVE this 'SO SO MuCH'"

output_string_1 = pat.sub(lambda match: match.group().lower(), input_string_1)
output_string_2 = pat.sub(lambda match: match.group().lower(), input_string_2)

print(input_string_1)
print(output_string_1)
print(input_string_2)
print(output_string_2)
```